# Can a Visual Studio produced static library, be stripped of symbols?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, static-libraries, symbols

I'll divide this questions in 3 parts:

1. I would like to produce a static library and **strip** off its symbols. (Debug info is already not included)
   Similar to the strip command in linux. Can it be done?
2. Is there an equivalent tool in windows env, to the **nm** tool in linux?
3. When creating a static library using VS2008. Is it possible to define a script that will **exclude** some of the produced .obj files out of the build and out of  the static lib?
   Can it be **dynamic**? I mean I'd define a compilation mode **in the script** and this would result in specific object files being excluded from the build

Comment: A library without symbols is as useful as Write-Only Memory.

Answer (score 3):

If anything is visible that you feel should not be, try declaring it with the "static" keyword.  This tells the compiler that it is accessible only to the current module.

Comment: This only does half the work. The library still contains the symbols, but they can be removed: on linux, by `strip -x ...`, on Windows, i don't know how - and that is the question!

Comment: Actually I just compiled a simple file that declared two functions, one static and one not and the static function does _not_ appear in the .lib file (verified with a hex editor).  It appears that this does what the OP wants.

Comment: I can't find a way to remove individual symbols from the final library, the /REMOVE option mentioned in another answer only seems to remove entire .obj files from the output library.

Comment: @Jimbo, if you just declare (and define) static function, it does not appear in compiled file. Though, if you actually use it, it gets included.

Answer (score 2):

1. No, how do you think the users of the static library would link to it without knowing where are the symbols they use defined?
2. Yes, try the [DUMPBIN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177429) utility.
3. Well, yes. You can run the `LIB` utility with `/REMOVE:foo`.

That said, I think you are doing something that either is not worth doing or could be done a lot simpler than with removing library members.

Answer (score 2):

There are cases where it would be convenient to be able to strip out all but a small number of "exported" public symbols, but it's not really feasible.

A static library is little more than a collection of .obj files.  The internal dependencies haven't been resolved yet, and they won't be resolved until link time.

For example, if your .lib consists of foo.obj and bar.obj, and there's a call in foo.obj to a function defined in bar.obj, then that symbol must be available at link time, even if nothing outside of the library should be able to see it.

For that reason, you cannot strip the symbols (with the possible exception of file-scope static symbols).  Even class methods that are protected or private (in the C++-sense) will exist in the symbol table, since the enforcement of the visibility is a compile-time issue, not a link-time one.

In contrast, a dynamic library is a standalone binary that has already been linked.  References from foo.obj to bar.obj have already been resolved.  Thus a DLL can be stripped of symbols except for the ones that must be exported (and even those can be renamed or replaced by ordinals).

If your DLL exposes a simple C API, then you're all set.  But if you want to expose a C++ class, you're probably going to end up exporting all of its methods, even the protected and private ones (since inlining in the external application might result in direct calls to private methods).

Comment: I'm curious about the downvote.  Anyone care to comment so that I can improve my answer?

Comment: The first sentence in your answer is what we also are trying to achieve. So far, the options seem to be 1) declare all unneeded symbols static, 2) put unneeded symbols in unnamed namespace, 3) rename unneeded symbols to some garbage (if obfuscation is your goal). The first two options should be combined with unity build to make sure the private cross-object symbils are no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

I kept finding the names of certain (but not all) static functions in .obj files produced by VS2010. Interestingly, they were visible in my Release .obj files but not the Debug .obj files. I just used cygwin strings to perform the search:

```
$ strings myObjectFile.obj | grep myStaticFunctionName
```

I tracked it down to the "Whole Program Optimization = Yes" setting ("/GL"). When I switched this to "No" the function names no longer appear.

Update: As a followup test I opened the "cleansed" myObjectFile.obj in vim and I can still find them (with either :set encoding=utf-8 or :set encoding=latin1). I'm not sure why strings was missing the matches. Oh well.